# What is the difference between \(\((.+?)\)\) and \(\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\) in Regexp?

Tags: regex

When I try `\(\((.+?)\)\)` and `\(\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\)` in [RegExr tool](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), I can't find the difference. Both highlighted the same texts. What could be the differences with or without `\s*`. Or what could be the good reason to have `\s*`?

I used the following sample texts.

```
I ((   a verb, past tense   )) to the sandwich shop across the street for lunch
yesterday. I go there at least ((a number)) times a week. They have the best
Philly Cheesesteak, full of ((a plural noun)) and ((a plural noun)) and gooey,
stringy ((a noun)).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second pattern with explicit white-characters (`\s*`), trim the leading and trailing white-characters from the capturing group. However the global match doesn't change.

To see the different behaviour with gskinner, you can try this replacement with the two patterns : `"#$1#"`  (where $1 is the capturing group)

Comment: Thanks, I have forgotten this word.